# Hide TabHost on scroll listview

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, android-tabhost

I'm trying to hide the TabHost when I scroll up the ListView and show it again when I scroll down, but I don't know why when I scroll up, only the last item of the tabhost is hiding and showing again, here is how I'm doing it, I call the method "HideTab" in my FragmentLitos.

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());

        mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.tabFrameLayout);
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(null);


        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("home").setIndicator(getTabIndicator(mTabHost.getContext(), R.string.inst, R.drawable.home)),
                FragmentLitos.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("prop").setIndicator(getTabIndicator(mTabHost.getContext(), R.string.prop, R.drawable.proposito)),
                FragmentPropositos.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("fav").setIndicator(getTabIndicator(mTabHost.getContext(), R.string.fav, R.drawable.heart)),
                FavFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("chat").setIndicator(getTabIndicator(mTabHost.getContext(), R.string.msg, R.drawable.chat)),
                MsgFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("user").setIndicator(getTabIndicator(mTabHost.getContext(), R.string.perfil, R.drawable.user)),
                FragmentTab.class, null);

        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

                if(tabId.equals("user")){

                    NavigationMain.Perfil();

                }
            }
        });

        return mTabHost;
    }

    private View getTabIndicator(Context context, int title, int icon) {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        ln = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.layout_tab);
        iv.setImageResource(icon);
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setText(title);

        return v;
    }


    public void HideTab(final JazzyListView list){

        list.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            int mLastFirstVisibleItem = 0;

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                if (view.getId() == list.getId()) {
                    final int currentFirstVisibleItem = list.getFirstVisiblePosition();

                    if (currentFirstVisibleItem > mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
                        v.animate().translationY(-v.getBottom()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();
                    } else if (currentFirstVisibleItem < mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
                        v.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()).start();
                    }

                    mLastFirstVisibleItem = currentFirstVisibleItem;
                }
            }
        });

    }
```